# Delete Features of a layer from PostgreSQL on QGIS itself

Tags: qgis, postgresql, delete, connection

I have layers that I need to edit using QGIS that I import from my company's PostgreSQL server. I currently have the ability to add features, for example the line that I have drawn below:

[image: PostgreSQL line feature added using QGIS]

However, after toggling editing mode and saving the line I have no way of deleting the feature that I drew (for example, if there was a mistake) from within QGIS itself. My only option at the moment is to access the PostgreSQL backend and delete the feature there.

I checked if it's possible to delete using the attribute table but there doesn't seem to be an option there either:

[image: Attribute table with no delete option]

Could someone point out a method for me to delete the selected feature from within QGIS itself? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue could be due to the unavailability of a primary key in the table.

This can be resolved by creating a **primary key** in that table where the layer is comprised.

A primary key on the table allows you to easily select individual rows for deletion based on their unique identifier.